# Xamarin: Native linking error in fresh installation

Tags: firebase, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

Recently I moved my project to a fresh installation of macOS. I installed Xcode, Visual Studio Mac and Xamarin.iOS, then I retrieved the last build of the project from git server. My configuration is as follows:

- macOS Mojave 10.14
- Xcode 10.1
- Visual Studio for Mac 7.6
- Xamarin.iOS 12.2

My problem is that the project no longer builds. I keep getting native linking errors, the build output can be seen below:

> /Users/u/Projects/appname/clang: Error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (prj)
>   /Users/u/Projects/appname/error MT5209: Error: warning: directory not
>   found for option '-FFInstncID-3.2.1/Frameworks' (prj) Native linking
>   /Users/u/Projects/appname/error MT5209: Error: warning: directory not
>   found for option '-FFAnlytcs-5.1.4/Frameworks' (prj) Native linking
>   /Users/u/Projects/appname/error MT5209: Error: warning: directory not
>   found for option '-FFAnlytcs-5.1.4/Frameworks' (prj) Native linking
>   /Users/u/Projects/appname/error MT5209: Error: warning: directory not
>   found for option '-FGAppM-5.1.4/Frameworks' (prj) Native linking
>   /Users/u/Projects/appname/error MT5209: Error: framework not found
>   FirebaseInstanceID (prj) Native linking
>   /Users/u/Projects/appname/MTOUCH: Error MT5201: Native linking failed.
>   Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -ObjC
>   -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz (MT5201) (prj) /Users/u/Projects/appname/MTOUCH: Error MT5202: Native linking failed.
>   Please review the build log. (MT5202) (prj)

The problem seems to be related to Firebase packages, but I cannot figure out how. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Delete the folder bin and obj ,then rebuild your project.

Comment: I should have mentioned since the beginning, deleting bin&obj then rebuilding won't help.